# Polymer 1.0 dom-repeat does not trigger filter

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Have a simple `paper-card` with an `iron-ajax` which is being iterated ok but the filter I have made never triggers. The JSON being fetched via the iron-ajax has an integer value for the day of the week and I only want to have the ones with value of 0.

Tried the filter field with following values:

```
filter="{{isMonday}}"
filter="{{isMonday(item)}}"
filter="isMonday"
filter="isMonday(item)"
```

All of these with and without the `observe`

Component code:

```
<dom-module id="se-ligor">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-bind">
            <iron-ajax auto
                       url="http://localhost:5000/leagues/1"
                       handle-as="json"
                       last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}">
            </iron-ajax>
            <template name="my-paper" is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse]]" filter="{{isMonday}}" observe="dayofweek">
                <paper-card heading="[[item.name]]">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        [[item.description]]
                        [[item.dayofweek]]
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-actions">
                        <paper-button>Some action</paper-button>
                    </div>
                </paper-card>

            </template>


        </template>

    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "se-ligor",
        isMonday: function (item) {
            console.log(item.dayofweek);
            if (item.dayofweek == 0)
                return True;
        }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The [`dom-bind`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-bind) template is intended for binding only in `index.html`, not in `dom-module`, so that template should be removed.
2. The `filter` property takes the name of a method without delimiters (i.e., no brackets) on your Polymer constructor object.

   ```
   <!-- in <dom-module> -->
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[x]]" filter="isMonday" observe="dayofweek">...</template>

   <script>
     Polymer({
       isMonday: function(item) {...}
     });
   </script>
   ```
3. `isMonday` contains a typo in `return True`. In JavaScript, the keyword is lowercase: `true`.

[plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/oGAib25eV67HoKbyOxvo?p=preview)